# How do Transactions Per Second work on Hedera

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

Suppose I send 1000 transactions per second and the finality is 2-3 sec. Will it take 2-3 sec to finalize all of those 1000 transactions? Or will it be a finalize delay difference between the first and last transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Each individual transaction will finalise within a few seconds so yes if the consensus latency is say 4s, they will each reach consensus in 4s from when they were received by a node. Since it will take you 1s to send all 1000, it will take 5s overall for all 1000 to reach consensus.

The analogy I sometimes use to distinguish throughput and latency is to use the difference between the speed of light and sound.
The time it takes for a flash of light or sound to reach someone is latency.
Now, you can flash or sound once a second or 100 times a second, that's throughput. The fact it takes sound longer to travel to its destination (latency) doesn't prevent 100 sounds being sent in one second.